# Get details of currently processing requests from IIS

Tags: iis, request, iis-7

My application is facing some issues while processing some requests. It happens randomly. But when the issue happens the requests get stuck in IIS. We can see the stuck requests in the Request section as shown in the below image

[image: IIS Requests section]

Question:

1. Is there a way to know the exact action [right now its only showing the request is to .svc file]
2. Is there a way to know the parameters that are passed to the stuck request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to capture a hang **dump** snapshot.
You could achieve this by using procdump, debug diagnostic tool etc.
If you don't know how to analyze dump file, debug diagnostic analysis tool will help you acehive this and you only need to read the report.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h

If you wanna deep analyze the dump file, then you could use windbg and mex extension.

**!clrstack2** will show the managed callstack.

**!mex.aspxpagesext** will show all concurrent requests' URL and its thread ID.